How does `jackc/pgx` works with multiply hosts
I have a PostreSQL cluster where I have a master and a slave. I have seen that pgx/pgxpool supports simultaneous connection to multiple hosts, but I do not understand how requests will be executed then. Can pgx understand where the master is? (I didn't find that he could do that.) And will pgx work at all if I have a master and a slave, and only readonly requests can be executed on the slave.
Please help me figure out the issue
I had an idea that the requests would be scattered round robin, but I did not find confirmation. And I don't know what will happen if the write request gets to the slave.
I understand roughly how you can write a wrapper around a pool so that it supports such an architecture, but I don't understand whether it is necessary or not

There is pgx/pgxpool, which handles a pool of connections to the same host. Where did you get the information for “pgx/pgxpoll”?

@eik, That's right, I made a mistake, thanks

regarding multiple hosts: pgx reimplements the same rules on connection string attributes as postgresql's implementation.
PostgreSQL doc mentions a round robin until one connection matches the criteria (connection is established, and target_session_attrs is matched)

link to postgres doc:

connection string
multiple hosts


It is possible to specify multiple hosts to connect to, so that they are tried in the given order.


target_session_attrs (for a connection to master, you probably want to set target_session_attrs=primary or target_session_attrs=read-write)


This option determines whether the session must have certain properties to be acceptable. It's typically used in combination with multiple host names to select the first acceptable alternative among several hosts.


On the pgx side of things:
The doc pgx.ParseConfig will lead you (2 links) to pgconn.ParseConfig
The documentation explicitly mentions multiple hosts support, the support for target_session_attrs is less explicit -- it is implied by the fact that PGTARGETSESSIONATTRS is supported, and by the link to connection string attributes -- but it is supported.
In pgx code, the validation for target_session_attrs at connection goes through one of the ValidateConnectTargetSessionAttrs* functions

Thanks for the answer! I still have one more question. If I set target_session_attrs for my PostgreSQL hosts, and while the program is running, the master will crash and the slave will become the master. Will this be handled automatically by the driver or should I implement it myself?

Once the slave is promoted to master: yes, any action from pgx that starts with "open a new connection" will work. pgxpool, for example, will automatically close failing connections and open new ones.

To give an illustration: we have code that listens on postgresql events. For this purpose, we open a connection which is handled outside of a pool, and which will remain open for long period of times. For that specific connection, we handle the reconnect and retry loop on error ourselves. The connection string, though, is static and says host=server1,server2 target_session_attrs=primary

It turns out that as soon as the slave becomes the master. pgxpool will recreate the pools, and the pool that used to be read-only will become read-write?
